# Motion compensation for stripmap SAR

Tags: radar, motion-compensation

I am trying to perform motion compensation for an airborne stripmap SAR data following the book [Synthetic Aperture Radar Processing by Franceschetti and Lanari](https://www.worldcat.org/title/synthetic-aperture-radar-processing/oclc/39936797). The algorithm flowchart is on page 145. My questions are:

1. Can I use the same phase equation given for 1st order MoCo for range resampling?
2. What is the right domain for performing these compensations? My understanding is that the range resampling can be done in frequency domain to achieve a shift in time domain and the phase compensations can to be done (via multiplications) in time domain for removing the phase error $ e^{j \frac{4 \pi \delta(r)}{\lambda}}$.

Comment: This is not an exactly easy to track book, do you think you could take a photo of the page you are refering to?

Comment: I am not familiar with that book but mocomp is generally done after waveform removal and in the RF x slow-time domain, such that the mocomp locus (whether it's a point or a line) has zero phase change in this domain.

Comment: Here is the photo link: https://imgur.com/P1nSlD6. I figured out the right domain for phase corrections (as asked it Q2), it's multiplications in time domain. However, the targets are resolved in wrong azimuth positions and there appear aliases. Not sure about the reason. Also, I still need to know the range resampling procedure (as asked in Q1). Thanks for your help.